# Specify a "-" in a sed pattern

Tags: regex, linux, unix, stream, sed

I'm trying to find a '-' character in a line, but this character is used for specifying a range. Can I get an example of a sed pattern that will contain the '-' character?

Also, it would be quicker if I could use a pattern that includes all characters except a space and a tab.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`'-'` specifies a range only between square brackets.

For example, this:

```
sed -n '/-/p'
```

prints all lines containing a `'-'` character.  If you want a `'-'` to represent itself between square brackets, put it immediately after the `[` or before the `]`.  This:

```
sed -n '/[-x]/p'
```

prints all lines containing either a `'-'` or a `'x'`.

This pattern:
    `[^ <tab>]`

matches all characters other than a space and a tab (note that you need a literal tab character, not "`<tab>`").

Comment: Thanks, once again you UNIX are of extreme help. This will definitely shorten my code.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find a dash, specify it outside a character class:

```
/-/
```

If you want to include it in a character class, make it the first or last character:

```
/[-a-z]/
/[a-z-]/
```

If you want to find anything except a blank or tab (or newline), then:

```
/[^ \t]/
```

where, I hasten to add, the '`\t`' is a literal tab character and not backslash-t.

Answer (score 0):

find "-" in file

```
 awk '/-/' file
```